# Cannot activate my custom permission in my code

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to ask users to agree with the disclaimer that I have provided in my application, and then if they agreed, next time they are using the app, we just re-show them the disclaimer for a few seconds without asking to click on anything and redirect them to the application. The best way I could have come up with it was, using a custom permission and however I did add permission commands to my manifest I could not figure out how to actually activate the permission in my code:

```
import java.util.jar.Manifest;

public class Language extends Activity {

    Button engBut, fraBut;
  //  public static int j;


   public  void click (View view){

     //  j=1;

       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);


    }

    public void fraClick (View view){

     //   j=2;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_language);

        ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);

        ImageView montfortLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.montfortLogo);

        montfortLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.k);

        logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.j);

        engBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.engBut);

        engBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Language.this);

                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("DISCLAIMER");
                builder.setMessage(R.string.result_disclaimer);

                builder.setNegativeButton("Get me out of here.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();

                    }
                });
                    builder.setPositiveButton("I agree.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            intent.setAction("com.techideas4you.pharamacy.MyAction");
                            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
                builder.show();
            }
        });




        fraBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fraBut);

        Log.i("Locale", String.valueOf(Locale.getDefault()));


    }
}
```

This was my first page code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.ex"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission android:name="testDisclaimer" android:label="DISCLAIMER" 
     android:description="@string/result_disclaimer"/>
       
    <uses-permission android:name="testDisclaimer"/>


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityQuestion"
            android:icon="@drawable/home"
            android:label="Home"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityResult"
            android:icon="@drawable/home"
            android:label="Home"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Language">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.techideas4you.pharamacy.MyAction" 
         />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>
         </application>

         </manifest>
```

and this is my manifest if anybody could help me out here I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  `android:protectionLevel="dangerous"` to the declaration of your permission else it will be granted automatically and users will not be presented with a dialog although you call `requestPermission()`.

```
<permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.testDisclaimer" android:label="DISCLAIMER"
            android:description="@string/result_disclaimer"
            android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>

<uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.testDisclaimer"/>
```

In order to have the runtime show the disclaimer, you have to call

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{"your.package.name.permission.testDisclaimer"}, 42);
```

The result (whether user agreed) will be transmitted to you in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 42 && grantResults != null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission  " + permissions[0] + (grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED ? "" : " NOT ") + " granted! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Please note that by using the permission system, you also have to cope with the fact that users will NOT be shown the permission-request-disguised-as-disclaimer if they

> [...]  turned down the permission request in the past and chose the
>   Don't ask again option in the permission request system dialog [...]

(quoted from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#make-the-request)).

So maybe simply writing a flag to `SharedPreferences` will do the job just as well.